# Zend Framework dispatching frontcontroller or run Zend Application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, bootstrapping

Recently I started out with developing in Zend Framework. I am using Zend Framework 1.11 since 2.0 is still in development and I can find more information on 1.11.

I have followed multiple tutorials and am trying to combine them for a project I am working on.

The thing is, and I just dont quite understand this. In the one tutorial the bootstrap file initialises `Zend_Application` and then bootstraps it and then runs this.

The other tutorial I was following is using `Zend_Layout` with MVC and dispatches the `Frontcontroller`.

What is the best practice for this? I need to use `Zend_Layout` and dispatching this and running the `Frontcontroller`/`Zend_application` gives me the exact same result.

I tried looking for the correct anwser but I cant find it..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Zend_Application**, ofcourse You can easily dispatch from the Frontcontroller, but it's the `old way` of dispatching ZF based apps.

Zend_Application was added later, and now it's best way to dispatch Your App 'coz of bootstrap & its resources :) You still can use frontcontroller's plugins etc.

Zend_Tool can create project for You and enable the layout. You can do it all from config file, thanks to Zend_Application :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using Zend_Application. You can configure your layout in your config file.

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

[Here is a good tutorial to look at](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

Comment: I followed that exact tutorial and a tutorial on Zend_Layout from Rob Allen, his tutorials seem to be easier to understand then other ones. Quick question, is it true that configuring a layout path autmatically initializes Zend Layout?

Comment: Yeh, it will load it if there is a layout script in that folder